# Co-buyer on car loan

Tags: united-states, auto-loan, arizona

I thought I was a co-signer on a car loan and found out after I was actually a co-buyer. The other co-buyer made 2 payments and is having trouble making the third. I have serious issues with paying on a loan for something that isn’t in my possession. I am listed first on the title and if she continues to not pay the loan is there any way to have my name removed from the title or take possession of the car. She Has been telling me she “paid it and doesn’t understand why it’s not showing that she paid”, and I’m at my at my wits end trying to determine what if any options I have. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: #1 This is what happens when you co-sign for a loan.  #2 Ask her for proof from her bank website that *she “paid it*.  #3 Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: What country (and, if the US, the state)?

Comment: Never, ever co-sign on a car loan. ever.

Comment: I’m in US, Arizona. I thought we were close friends, I’m learning that I’m only her good friend when she needs something. Hard (& expensive) lesson being learned...... I’m just wondering what options I might have other then just ignoring the situation and waiting for it to get repossessed.

Comment: @Pumba76 keep in mind a repossession will put a ding on your credit and may ruin your relationship with the finance company.  Also they may sue you.  You are far better off taking the car back, selling it, and paying off the loan.

Comment: Problem is both our names are on the title, but mine is listed first if that matters

Answer (score 1):

Cosigning is always a dubious proposition and it seems that you got caught in something that is fairly common.  That is the car salesmen lied to you about your position on the loan and title.  They did something other than what they said and you desired.  However, they may have helped you out in this situation.

The bottom line is that you own the car.  You can take possession of it.  In fact, you can do so even if she makes the payments.  [See this question and answer.](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/120041/i-took-over-the-payments-on-my-sisters-car-but-it-is-left-in-her-name/120047?noredirect=1#comment236842_120047)

You asked for some suggestions, so here are mine:

1. Buy cars for cash, never get another car loan.  Get out of your car loans ASAP!
2. Never cosign for anyone for any reason what-so-ever.